# error while catching pytrends.exceptions.ResponseError in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to catch an exception that is thrown by google when they lock you out of their servers in pytrends.

Here is the exact error message I get:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytrends/request.py",     line 101, in _get_data
'response with code {0}.'.format(response.status_code), response=response)
pytrends.exceptions.ResponseError: The request failed: Google returned a response with code 429.
```

I tried running `except pytrends.exceptions.ResponseError:` but when I do that I get an attribute error `AttributeError: 'TrendReq' object has no attribute 'exceptions'`

If anyone knows the way to catch this it would be great to know, thanks!

Comment: I imported pytrends using pip3, so the command `pip3 install pytrends`

Comment: I tried it and it worked.  Reproducing the error would be quite difficult because you have to run quite a few requests.  it tends to only block me after 500 requests, but since it had just blocked me and I was still blocked, I was able to recreate it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To import the error :

```
from pytrends.exceptions import ResponseError
```

Then you can catch it :

```
try:
    pass  # normal behaviour
except ResponseError:
    pass  # treat your error
```